# Sharepoint REST api GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl returning syetem folder

Tags: rest, office365api

I am using GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl REST api to get Folders and Files from Office365 document library. I am usng below query

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')?$expand=Folders,Files

It is returning Folders and Files as expected, but also giving one folder named 'Forms' how can i exclude that?

Also using the same call how can i get author name(modified by).